# SQL Server 2000 : return a value when no record is returned

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2000, vba

I have a list of about 1500 part numbers in an Excel document. I want to insert these part numbers in a query to pull descriptions from my database and then copy/paste the results back into the Excel document.

The problem is some of the part numbers in my list aren't in my database, so when I go to copy/paste the results of my query into Excel they aren't going to match up because some of the part numbers in the query do not return a result.

```
SELECT ITEM.ITEMNO, ITEM.DESCRIPTION 
FROM ITEMS 
WHERE ITEM.ITEMNO IN ('1500','Part','Numbers')
```

It seems like a simple concept and my google searches have returned a lot of results, but they usually involve multiple tables and unions/joins. I just can't translate the examples I have seen to my query. If VBA is a better option then I am all ears.

Comment: What exactly is the problem or question?

Comment: Using my example query: 1500 and Numbers are in my database. Part is not in my database. The results would not have parts at all. I just need parts to still take up a row in the results even though there is no record.

Comment: What I typically do in this situation: while collecting the query values populate a Dictionary with key=query_value and value=range_with_theQuery_value.  Run the SQL and then loop through the recordset, using the Dictionary to determine which row(s) to write each result record to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.ITEMNO, IFNULL(i.DESCRIPTION, 'N/A')
from (
    select '1500' as ITEMNO
    union all select 'Part'
    union all select 'Numbers'
) a
left outer join ITEMS i on a.ITEMNO = i.ITEMNO
```